# Execution continues only If the window is terminated in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt Creator for a GUI application. I am using Ubuntu OS.

I have two buttons in GUI,but it wont work unless the other pressed.

If I press one button it wont show any output, If I close the main Window output is printed on console.

this is header file

```
#ifndef MYMAINWINDOW_H
#define MYMAINWINDOW_H
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>


class MyMainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MyMainWindow(QWidget * parent = 0);
  virtual ~ MyMainWindow();



 private slots:
  void clickedRun();
  void filechooser();


private:

  QPushButton *button,*button2;
  std::string getFileExt(std::string s);

 };
#endif // MYMAINWINDOW_H
```

This is cpp file

```
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>
QStringList Listoffiles;
std::string headerfilename,sourcefile;
MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow(QWidget * parent) : QMainWindow (parent)
{

    setWindowTitle("welcome");
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
    QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton(this);

    button->setText("Choose Files");
    button2->setText("Run");

    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(filechooser()));
    QObject::connect(button2, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(clickedRun()));

    button->move(100, 100);
    button->show();
    button2->move(300,100);
    button2->show();


    setWindowTitle("Pushbutton Clicked Signal Test");
    show();

}

MyMainWindow::~MyMainWindow()
{
}
  void MyMainWindow::clickedRun()
  {
       qDebug() << "inside run \n";

  }

  void MyMainWindow::filechooser()
  {
      QFileDialog dialog(this);
      dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
      //dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
      if(dialog.exec())
      {
          Listoffiles = dialog.selectedFiles();

      }
      std::cout << Listoffiles.count() <<" Files selected \n";
      int i = 0;
      for(QString q: Listoffiles)
      {
        qDebug()<<"how many times "<< ++i;

      std::string file = q.toUtf8().constData();
      if(getFileExt(file)=="h")
      {
          headerfilename = file;
           std::cout << "\nIncluded header file : ";
           std::cout << headerfilename;

      }else if(getFileExt(file)=="cpp")
      {
          sourcefile = file;
          std::cout << "\nFile selected to run : " << sourcefile << std::endl;
      }
    }
      dialog.close();
  }

  std::string MyMainWindow::getFileExt(std::string s){
  size_t i = s.rfind('.',s.length());
  if(i!= std::string::npos)
  {
  return (s.substr(i+1,s.length()-1));
  }
  return ("");
  }
```

and this is main file

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "MyMainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MyMainWindow window;

  //window.setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("MainWindow"));
  window.resize(700,500);
  window.show();

  return app.exec();

}
```

How can I solve this issue.?

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). [Build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) (on command line) your code with `g++ -g -Wall` then [use `gdb`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Also, read carefully [documentation of `QFileDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html). It probably is a modal dialog.

Comment: there is no reason to invoke show() in the constructor, you are actually calling window.show() some when later...

Comment: It got solved. I just change the execution in filechooser function.Everything working perfectly.